# How to recognize and delete Ubuntu partitions from Windows 8 Dual Boot Machine?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

About a year ago I installed Ubuntu 13.10 side-by-side with Windows 8.

A few weeks later I updated it to 14.04 (only so I could stop seeing the "available updates" message) and I updated my Windows 8 to 8.1 (because my laptop gave me no choice on the matter).

After I did all that, something weird happened which caused my laptop not to show me my operating systems when I powered it on, and instead it went straight to Windows 8 all the time. However this didn't mean I couldn't enter my Ubuntu system, but I had to follow these steps:

1. Turn on the machine by pressing the Assist system so I could get into the UEFI loader, and from there I could enter my BIOS.
2. Change my BIOS mode to legacy and restart and wait for a not-so-nice message saying it couldn't find any operating systems.
3. Power off, and repeat step 1, and change BIOS mode back to UEFI.
4. Restart and it would show me that screen, asking which OS I wanted to boot.

Now, at that time I was too busy to try and fix that. And then I stopped using Ubuntu altogether. One, because I got a Mac, and since they're both UNIX based systems I could do on the Mac everything I could do in Ubuntu; and two, because they now keep a Ubuntu machine in my office so I can store and test any new projects I develop.

So, at the moment I don't really need Ubuntu, so much as I'm starting to need the space it takes, and I want to delete it from my Hard Drive.
For this purpose I watched some Youtube videos, but they led me nowhere, since they show their Computer Management window in Windows 8, and it only shows 4 partitions. 2 for Linux and 2 for Windows, but in my case, for some reason, I have many more, and I don't want to delete anything if that could mean damaging my Windows partition... I can't uplad images yet so I will list my partitions here.

```
_________________________________________________________________________________________

Volume  Layout  Type  File_System  Status                   Capacity  Free_Space  %_Free

_________________________________________________________________________________________        
        Simple  Basic              Healthy(OEM Partition)   260 MB    260 MB      100%
        Simple  Basic              Healthy(Recovery Part)   1.44 GB   1.44 GB     100%
        Simple  Basic              Healthy(EFI System Pa)   260 MB    260 MB      100%
        Simple  Basic              Healthy(Recovery Part)   450 MB    450 MB      100%
        Simple  Basic              Healthy(Primary Part)    1 MB      1 MB        100%
        Simple  Basic              Healthy(Primary Part)    32.11 GB  32.11 GB    100%
        Simple  Basic              Healthy(Primary Part)    7.88 GB   7.88 GB     100%
        Simple  Basic              Healthy(Recovery Part)   350 MB    350 MB      100%
        Simple  Basic              Healthy(Recovery Part)   30.09 GB  30.09 GB    100%
        Simple  Basic              Healthy(OEM Partition)   8,02 GB   8.02 GB     100%
        Simple  Basic              Healthy(Primary Part)    14.35 GB  14.35 GB    100%
(E:)    Simple  Basic  NTFS        Healthy(Primary Part)    250.00 GB 87.79 GB    35%
(C:)    Simple  Basic  NTFS        Healthy(*)               608.57 GB 350.50 GB   63%

*Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition.
```

I don't know why I have so many partitions... If I remember correctly I always had more partitions than normal. But this is ridiculous.
However the E partition is one that i created so I could share some specific filed between Windows and Linux (which backfired because I almost never could access them from Ubuntu).

So, that's it... As a question I'll just quote my title: "How to recognize and delete Ubuntu partitions from Windows 8 Dual Boot Machine?".
Or if possible, how to completely delete Ubuntu, by booting into it first.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot Ubuntu Live from your CD/Pen Drive
2. Then use `gParted` / `Disk Utility` to identify the ubuntu partitions (Usually ext4 and swap space)
3. Then format those partitions

> You can also use the gParted live to live boot and use the gParted application